# This code should give output as the given format

Tags: java, string

This is code in java for string.

```
int a=6;
int b=7;

System.out.println(a+"\"+b);
```

I want to comes the output is `6\7`.

Comment: Check how to write '\' in Java, presumably you need to escape it (`"\\"`, presumably)

Answer (score 4):

write this code:

```
System.out.println(a+"\\"+b);
```

Answer (score 3):

In literal Java strings the backslash is an escape character. The literal string `"\\"` is a single backslash.

In regular expressions, the backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash. This regular expression as a Java string, becomes `"\\\\"`. That's right: 4 backslashes to match a single one.

Comment: I'd +1 this for a full explanation, but I'm afraid that the regex explanation only confuses the issue: it's correct, but I don't think the OP is at the right level to get that information just yet.

Comment: I thought I would explain the whole thing, its a bit more complex, but hopefully he understands it and he will never have any issues with the backslash again :)

Comment: Fair enough. I took the liberty to format it a bit.